# mysql Left join, mysql does an inner join?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to do a left join but mysql just does an inner join?
whats wrong with my query?

```
select av.*, ap.* 
from tbl_available av 
left join tbl_appointment ap 
on av.avHours = ap.appointmenttime 
where av.avCalendarId = 2 
and (ap.calendarid = 2 or ap.calendarid= null)
and (ap.appointmentdate = "2012-10-01" or ap.appointmentdate = null)
and av.avDays = DayOfweek("2012-10-01")
order by avHours
```

mysql only gives those avHours who have a corresponding appointment

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't use `=` to check whether a field is null, you must use `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of these conditions:

```
and ap.calendarid = 2 
and ap.appointmentdate = "2012-10-01"
```

you only select rows from `tbl_appointment` which are not `null`.

If that's what you want - move them to the left join's `ON` part

Comment: Thanks man, this did the trick! :)
Stupid from me to forget this

Comment: Or you can change your where to "and (ap.calendarid is null or ap.calendarid = 2) and (ap.appointmentdate is null or ap.appointmentdate = '2012-10-01')"